# React: failed to compile // webpack problem

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My project can't be compiled anymore. It came suddenly , I didn't get why.
It seems to be related to webpack. Maybe I need to downgrade webpack the version before 5 but I don't see how to do it in React.
I managed to reduce errors from 90 to 7 with adding resolve:fallback  but I don't know what to do with others.
So, now I have these errors:

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'
WARNING in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/WorkerPool.js 25:4-29
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/jest-worker/build'

WARNING in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/base/BaseWorkerPool.js 122:19-46
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js 71:19-38
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js 83:15-28
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js 99:15-28
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js 20:19-39
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js 43:118-125
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

WARNING in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js 519:18-51
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'uglify-js/package.json' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'

WARNING in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js 596:18-51
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@swc/core/package.json' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'

WARNING in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js 678:18-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'esbuild/package.json' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'

WARNING in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/webpack/lib/[url]' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/webpack/lib/[url]'

WARNING in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/debug/ProfilingPlugin.js 29:14-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'inspector' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/webpack/lib/debug'

WARNING in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/serialization/ObjectMiddleware.js 679:18-34
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js 9:15-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'

ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/NodeThreadsWorker.js 29:15-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'

ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/messageParent.js 23:8-33
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'

ERROR in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js 481:6-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'uglify-js' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js 560:14-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@swc/core' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js 639:18-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'esbuild' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/FileSystemInfo.js 11:19-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules/webpack/lib'
Did you mean './module'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, /Users/yulia/Documents/DEV/JS_REACT/projects/arrosy-moved/node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

webpack compiled with 7 errors and 13 warnings
```

Comment: What's you node version?

Comment: Node version is 16.16.0. I upgraded after the errors, initially was 16.4